# How to display x-www-form-urlencoded format request with springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

##### My environment

springboot:2.6.4
springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.6

##### Probrem

I want to create an API definition to receive requests in x-www-form-urlencoded format.
Using @RequestBody will create a swagger-ui display with no Parameter notation, just the body. However, when receiving a request in x-www-form-urlencoded format, it is necessary to receive it with @RequestParam, and if this is done, the swagger-ui display is created as a query parameter.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/hoge")
public ResponseEntity<SampleResponse> postProc(
    @RequestParam("param1") int param1,
    @RequestParam("param2") String param2,
    @RequestParam("param3") String param3,
    HttpServletRequest request) {
　　・・・
}
```

[swagger-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyplc.png)

However, since there is no actual query parameter, I do not want to display the Parameter in the same way as when receiving a request with @RequestBody.
The display without parameters is correct, as in POST /user in the following link.

http://158.101.191.70:8081/swagger-ui/4.5.0/index.html#/user/createUser

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: did you find any fix? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution for you:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/hoge", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<SampleResponse> postProc(
    @RequestPart("param1") int param1,
    @RequestPart("param2") String param2,
    @RequestPart("param3") String param3,
    HttpServletRequest request) {
　　・・・
}
```

In a perfect world, you could stick to the `@RequestParam` but I believe there is currently a bug with springdoc that make it impossible.

Comment: With your solution, requests from ARC are accepted and processed correctly. But the Swagger UI still displays the parameters as query parameters and tries to send them as query parameters.